# Gem error to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I try to install rails but I am faced to the following error.

Has somebody any idea how to resolve it ?

```
C:\Users\Utilisateur>gem -v
2.0.14

C:\Users\Utilisateur>gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (htt
ps://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Users\Utilisateur>gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (htt
ps://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http
://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but I ran the "Start command prompt with Ruby" as an administrator and tried the `gem install rails` and it worked.

Answer (score 14):

First try to update ruby gems.

```
gem update --system
```

The issue most likely is with your internet connection.

If you see this issue again, try

```
gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
```

You can add the not https source permanently like this

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]y
```

I want to give you one more tip:

Don't develop rails on windows. Ruby and rails and many gems are very UNIXy in their ways. Install virtualbox and ubuntu on a virtual machine and run you development for there.

Comment: Same problem see my new post. Any other idea ? I try since more than 1 hour by installing, uninstalling, ... I haven't got openssl...

Comment: Result is => Latest version currently installed. Aborting. No change for the previous command

Comment: thats strange cause the last version is 2.2.2. Look at the [rubygems download page](https://rubygems.org/pages/download) and see if you can find a way to update it

Comment: I will try to change the version and come back to tell if it works !

Comment: Great! Please delete your answer below.

Comment: Still a pb with 1.8.24 version : See C:\Users\Utilisateur>gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: Les blocs de contr¶le de mÚmoire ont ÚtÚ dÚtruits.
  (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: It might be a proxy problem. Look [here for solution](http://khylo.blogspot.in/2007/12/ruby-on-rails-headaches.html). The real answer to all you problems is; stop using windows. It will take you about one hour to set up [ubuntu on a vbox](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox)

Comment: No solution founded! I switched on Mac

Comment: That's a good decision. I suggested vbox cause its free. Good luck!

Comment: how about the ruby developers pull that "cross platform" lie from the site then?

Comment: Thanks a lot dude .. issue solved when using http instead of https. gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org

Answer (score 3):

You might have proxy in your system. So use sudo http_proxy=http://host:port gem install rails.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run 'gem install' as root to get this to work. I.e. 'sudo', which is less than ideal.

I suspect 'gem' has very poor error reporting and doesn't communicate the real cause from a permissions issue deep down the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In my country for some strange reason rubygems.org domain is blocked. So a vpn was the solution for me.

Answer (score -3):

My problem was I had configured a proxy in my network connection as @theBuzzyCoder said, so I simply changed my connection and it worked, I could install my gem (sass in my case)